# 1004 error when trying to insert formula with "vlookup"

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am new to vba (actually started yesterday) so please excuse my ignorance on details I should include in my question.

I am trying to use a macro to insert a formula containing "vlookup" into a cell in excel. However, if I try to run the macro, I get an error "1004 - application defined or object defined error"

The line that causes the issue:

```
Worksheets("Berechnungen").Cells(19, 10).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(R3C1;R9C1:R12C1;16;FALSE)"
```

I tried different formulas like

```
Worksheets("Berechnungen").Cells(19, 10).Formula = "=SUM(R3C4:R3C5)"
```

that all worked like a charm.

I am using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus, version 1708 in German language.

Please let me know if you require any additional information!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When inserting formulas via VBA you need to use "US-style" comma separator and not a semicolon, unless you use `FormulaLocal`.